# Не могу добавить картинку в imageView поверх новой картинки. Помогите пожалуйста!)

Tags: java, android

Создал photo app с двумя активити, один MainActivity с двумя ImageView, а второй Активти список с шаблонами png. Когда из галереи телефона загр. картинку в MainActivity и пытаюсь добавить из второго Активити картинку в MainActivity то в MainActivity обнуляются данные. Картинка загр. из галереи исчезает

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageView btnGallery;
    ImageView btnSave;
    ImageView btnCamera;
    ImageView btnMakets;
    ImageView btnPrint;
    ImageView imageView8, imageView7;
    private ViewGroup mainLayout;
    private static final String GALLERY = "GALLERY_REQUEST";
    private static final String CAMERA = "CAMERA_REQUEST";
    private static int GALLERY_REQUEST = 22131;
    private static int CAMERA_REQUEST = 13323;
    private int xDelta;
    private int yDelta;
    CameraPhoto cameraPhoto;
    GalleryPhoto galleryPhoto;
    android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar mToolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
        btnGallery = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btnGallery);
        btnCamera = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btnCamera);
        btnMakets = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.addMaket);
        mainLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayouts);
        imageView7 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView7);
        imageView8 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView8);
        imageView7.setOnTouchListener(onTouchListener());
        imageView8.setOnTouchListener(onTouchListener());
        imageView8.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.c);
        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolBar1);
        cameraPhoto = new CameraPhoto(getApplicationContext());
        galleryPhoto = new GalleryPhoto(getApplicationContext());

        btnMakets.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent newActiv = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ListMakets.class);
                startActivity(newActiv);
            }
        });

        btnCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                try {
                    startActivityForResult(cameraPhoto.takePhotoIntent(), CAMERA_REQUEST);
                    cameraPhoto.addToGallery();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

        btnGallery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivityForResult(galleryPhoto.openGalleryIntent(), GALLERY_REQUEST);

            }
        });

        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (bundle != null) {
            mToolbar.setTitle(savedInstanceState.getString("dataImages"));
            if (mToolbar.getTitle().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Тест")) {
                imageView7.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(MainActivity.this, R.drawable.cap));
            }
        }
    }

    private View.OnTouchListener onTouchListener() {
        return new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
                final int x = (int) event.getRawX();
                final int y = (int) event.getRawY();
                switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)view.getLayoutParams();
                        xDelta = x -lParams.leftMargin;
                        yDelta = y -lParams.topMargin;
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) view
                                .getLayoutParams();
                        layoutParams.leftMargin = x - xDelta;
                        layoutParams.topMargin = y - yDelta;
                        layoutParams.rightMargin = 0;
                        layoutParams.bottomMargin = 0;
                        view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                        break;
                }
                mainLayout.invalidate();
                return true;
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            if(requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST){
                String photoPath = cameraPhoto.getPhotoPath();
                try {
                    Bitmap bitmap = ImageLoader.init().from(photoPath).requestSize(356, 356).getBitmap();
                    imageView8.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
            else if(requestCode == GALLERY_REQUEST){
                Uri uri = data.getData();
                galleryPhoto.setPhotoUri(uri);
                String photoPath = galleryPhoto.getPath();
                try {
                    Bitmap bitmap = ImageLoader.init().from(photoPath).requestSize(356, 356).getBitmap();
                    imageView8.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putInt(GALLERY, GALLERY_REQUEST);
        outState.putInt(CAMERA, CAMERA_REQUEST);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        GALLERY_REQUEST = savedInstanceState.getInt(GALLERY);
        CAMERA_REQUEST = savedInstanceState.getInt(CAMERA);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }



    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}    



public class ListMakets extends AppCompatActivity{
    public ListView listView;
    private ImageView imageView;
    public android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list_makets);
        toolbar = (android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolBar);
        toolbar.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
        listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
        imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView7);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ListMakets.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.imgData));
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                switch (i){
                    case 0:
                        Intent intent = new Intent(ListMakets.this, MainActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("dataImages", listView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString());
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void finish() {
        super.finish();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean moveTaskToBack(boolean nonRoot) {
        return super.moveTaskToBack(nonRoot);
    }
}
```

Comment: В смысле, MainActivity пересоздаётся когда вы возвращаетесь со второй активити? И нет кода второй активити из которой вы устанавливаете картинку на первую.

Comment: Да, пересоздается когда возвращаюсь со второго активити

Comment: Значит системе не хватает памяти и она убивает активити, когда та уходит в бекграунд. Это нормальное поведение. Попробуйте сохранять состояние (переменную `photoPath`) в методе  `onSaveInstanceState` и восстанавливать (устанавливать картинку по этому пути заново) в `onCreate`.